# SQL Update add_time wrong date

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm having a little problem, everything works fine, but the column `add_time` is not importing the date like I want (2018-10-22 20:31) but it is making like this in the database: (0000-00-00 00:00:00)

Any idea of what I should add or change?

```
<?php

      mysqli_select_db($panel,"mydb");

      $group=$_POST['group'];
      $server=$_POST['server'];
      $aid=$_POST['aid'];

      $sql = "UPDATE admin SET gid='$group', sid='$server', add_time='NOW())' WHERE aid='$aid'";
      mysqli_close($panel); 
   ?>
```

Comment: take the ticks off of `NOW()` ?  And -- you have `NOW())` -- Extra  `)`

Comment: Zak's comment + You never run any query, so I don't know what's going on

Comment: @Zak thank you, it worked, im so dumb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the ticks off of `NOW()` -- And -- you have `NOW())` -- Extra `)`

```
$sql = "UPDATE admin SET gid='$group', sid='$server', add_time=NOW() WHERE aid='$aid'";
  mysqli_close($panel);
```

**IN ADDITION**

If you can `ALTER` your table so that you don't have to include `NOW()` in your query ..  It will update the field automatically on update --

```
ALTER TABLE admin 
 CHANGE add_time
        add_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
                 DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
                 ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```